# Can Volley be used to Get/Post data from AWS (DynamoDB)?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, android-volley

I'm a noob.

I have been researched Amazon's DynamoDB and Google's Volley extensively, however it is still not clear to me whether these two technologies can be used together (even thought they both support JSON, for example).

I think my questions stems from Volley expecting a URL parameter to get/post data to. Does my AWS table have a URL?

Answer (score 1):

In every DynamoDB [API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) request except for [ListTables](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_ListTables.html), you must specify a TableName. The TableName, combined with your AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and region/endpoint allows the DynamoDB service to perform operations on your table on your behalf. Each region has a different set of HTTP and HTTPS [endpoints](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#ddb_region). The table namespace of each region is distinct for each AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, so even if you have a table named "my_table" in us-west-1, that does not mean that you have a table named "my_table" in us-east-1. Even if you did have two tables with the same name in different regions, they would not necessarily have the same data.

To sum up, you want to use the DynamoDB [endpoints](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#ddb_region) as the URL to POST data to, and you will specify your credentials and table name as part of the body of each request.

Note that AWS requests are signed, so you may need to implement this logic and other boilerplate logic in your application if you use the HTTP DynamoDB API.

The [AWS Mobile SDK for Android](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/index.html) will create and sign your DynamoDB requests, and make the requests for you using abstractions of the DynamoDB API. For more examples, see the [Getting Started](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/dynamodb_om.html#getting-started) section in DynamoDB of the AWS Mobile SDK for Android.

Comment: Let's say I'm using objectMapper. How do i use it's save() method with volley when volley is expecting:

JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
        (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {}

Comment: The AWS SDK for Android by default uses HttpURLConnection as it's http client. However, you can plug your own http client in using the HttpClient interface. You can use this interface, and put your own http client in the AmazonDynamoDBClient constructor (all client constructors support this interface). Then use that AmazonDynamoDBClient to create the object mapper. Note, please read the HttpClient interface carefully as the SDK will have already signed the request, so it cannot be modified. Additionally the SDK wants to handle retry logic etc...